# Pressure due to a single photon

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, pressure, momentum

I'm interested in the pressure exerted on a material when a single photon is absorbed.

I have written the following expression for pressure:

$$
P = \frac{hf}{cA\Delta t},
$$
where $A$ is the area over which the force is exerted, $\Delta t$ is the time over which the force is exerted, $h$ is Planck's constant, $f$ is the frequency of the photon, and $c$ is the speed of light.

Something seems fishy.

Comment: This is like asking what is the pressure when a single atom is adsorbed onto a surface. Pressure comes from the average force when many such interactions are averaged over an area.

Comment: "Pressure" is a statistical phenomenon. What you get from a single impact is called [_impulse_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics))—change in momentum—of which the unit is Newton seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that $A$ is well-defined concept for a photon, and I'm not too sure about $\Delta t$ either. What *does* make sense is to interpret your expression as the mean pressure exerted per photon when  a decent number of randomly distributed photons lands normally on area $A$ of the absorber in time $\Delta t$.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Too many variables:

$$ f = c/\lambda $$

and by dimensional analysis:

$$ \Delta t \propto \lambda/c $$

and

$$ A \propto \lambda^2 $$

so

$$ P\propto \frac{hc/\lambda}{c\lambda^2\lambda/c} = \frac{hc}{\lambda^4} $$

Does that look better?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that does look better.

Answer (score -2):

It's incorrect to measure energy for a time interval without knowing rate of energy transference, power. So Pressure can be easily known from intensity of photons and rate of transportation of photons, thus $$p=\frac{\varepsilon}{c}$$

Answer given by **JEB** is incorrect because wavelength of light is in direction of propogation not along the dimension of incident area just because dimensionally it is equal.